# diable reactive behavior with using selectInput() function in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using selectInput in shiny UI for the dropdown option list. however, this one is reactive to my output table.

Can I disable this behaviour? because the table requires several more inputs and additionally I have a run button to trigger it once everything is all set.

Comment: You can try with isolate() in the server part where you generate the output

Comment: To build on @ValterBeaković's comment, `isolate()`is a great function (read more about it in [this article](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html)). But you may also find it very useful to read about "Using Action Buttons" ([here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html)). In addition to covering `isolate()`, it also covers `observeEvent()` and `eventReactive()`, as well as covering general patterns which depend on action buttons.